# Completion handler not being returned

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function which i wish to keep running if the count of the array the results are being appended to is less than 15 or if the query has been run 30 times. Everything seems to work except the `completionHandler` is never returned. (Could it be because its out of scope?)

**search Function**

```
  func search(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> () {
    let queryLimit = 20
    self.searchTerms = self.createArray()
    self.getData(searchTerms[self.searchCounter]){_ in
         if (self.searchCounter >= queryLimit || (parResults.count >= 15)){
            print("SEARCH COMPLETE")
            completionHandler(true)
        }
        else{
            self.searchCounter++
            self.search(){_ in
            }
            print("Query Count is \(self.searchCounter)")
            print("Results count is \(parResults.count))")
            if (self.searchCounter % 5 == 0){
                self.termCount+=150
            }
            if(self.searchCounter == queryLimit && parResults.count > 0){
                //DISPLAY PARTIAL RESULTS?
                print("PARTIAL")
               completionHandler(true)
            }
            //No results
            if(self.searchCounter == queryLimit && parResults.count == 0){
                //SHOW USER NOTICE TO CHANGE SETTINGS
                print("SHOW USER NOTICE TO CHANGE SETTINGS")
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Call to function**

```
func runSearch(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> () {
        search{
            msg in
            print("DONE")//Never executed
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if `(parResults.count < 15 && self.searchCounter <= queryLimit)` returns true?

Comment: Does the getData function actually work / does its block get called, or does it stall?

Comment: @jtbandes everything works except the completion handler in the `search` function

Comment: You need to debug the value of both searchCounter and parResults variables to get the issue with which condition is not meet. Also a best practice is to write false condition first then true latter.

Comment: I have multiple times, the condition is always met but the completionHandler cannot be returned for some strange reason @nikhil84

Comment: @george, how does your `getData` method implementation look like?

Comment: @george Ok I could u tell u more on objective c but not much idea on swift. Still If I find something then will post it here